# NPM install package compatible with specific version of another package

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

My package depends on `PackageA`. `PackageA` depends on `PackageB_Version2`. I now need to install `PackageC` which depends on `PackageB`. How can I force npm to install that `PackageC` which is compatible with existing version of `PackageB` (i.e., `PackageB_Version2`)?

Comment: may be you can install the package and check the updates if any

Answer (score 0):

NPM will install a version specific packaging you tell it the version #. From the docs:

`npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>`

`npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>`

So once you determine the version numbers and dependencies install with save to `package.json`  and you will have your version dependencies saved until you update them.